# How to convert this python data to JSON

Tags: python, json, discord.py

I'd like to know how can I convert this discord.py Message obj data to a JSON format. To be honest I have no idea what this is or what to do. Thanks.

```
<Message id=0000000000 channel=<TextChannel id=00000000000000 name='general' position=0 nsfw=False news=False category_id=0000000000000000> type=<MessageType.default: 0> author=<Member id=00000000000000 name='membername' discriminator='0000' bot=False nick=None guild=<Guild id=0000000000000000000 name='servername' shard_id=None chunked=False member_count=2>> flags=<MessageFlags value=0>>
```

Comment: Neither do we.  What's your desired output schema?  Do some research and post a code attempt.  Read this -> [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access different attributes of the `Message` instance like so:

```
message.content  # Whatever was written in the message
message.id  # 112233445566778899
# etc.
```

And these can then be put inside a dictionary to then be written to a json file.
As a side-note, you can just store the `message.id` and the `message.channel.id` and then just `channel.fetch_message(...` to get the object again. It's up to you how much you'll be storing and whether you'll need to get the original message object again.

Here's a short run-down of everything you'd need to know for storing and reading from json files:

```
>>> import json

# Creating a dictionary with some values
>>> data = {"foo": "bar", "key": "value"}

# Re-assigning specific values or inserting new ones in
>>> data["baz"] = 1234

# Opening a file and writing to it
>>> with open("db.json", "w+") as fp:
        # The kwargs are purely for beautification, just a preference
...     json.dump(data, fp, sort_keys=True, indent=4)

# Loading in data from a file
>>> with open("db.json", "r") as fp:
...     data = json.load(fp)

# Accessing the values
>>> data["foo"]
'bar'
>>> data["key"]
'value'
>>> data["baz"]
1234
```

---

### References:

- [`json.load()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load)
- [`json.dump()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump)
- [`discord.Message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message)
- [`Message.content`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.content)
- [`Message.id`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.id)
- [`TextChannel.fetch_message()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.fetch_message)

Answer (score 1):

I believe it’s YAML.

try [yaml to json](https://onlineyamltools.com/convert-yaml-to-json)

Result:

```
{
  "<Message id=0000000000 channel=<TextChannel id=00000000000000 name='general' position=0 nsfw=False news=False category_id=0000000000000000> type=<MessageType.default": "0> author=<Member id=00000000000000 name='membername' discriminator='0000' bot=False nick=None guild=<Guild id=0000000000000000000 name='servername' shard_id=None chunked=False member_count=2>> flags=<MessageFlags value=0>>"
}
```

Spacing is important revise it I’ve posted from mobile with a lot of difficulties